# How do I cancel an operation in alpine email client?

Tags: alpine-mail

Occasionally when I'm doing something in alpine, I'll forget and do the wrong thing (like open up my gmail folder when I meant to open my *other* IMAP account).

Then I have to wait for a few seconds for everything to finish.

I want to be able to cancel the operation and go to something else, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work.

Is it possible to cancel the current operation in Alpine?

Comment: given that we've only had 21 alpine questions in the past 6 years, and 1/3 of those are unanswered, I'm going to suggest a site like superuser.com (only 24 Q's there), or the [discussion list](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/alpine-info/)

Comment: Tag `alpine` is for Alpine Linux, not Alpine email client.

Comment: @JakubJirutka sounds like someone needs to update the tag wiki then, cause it's empty right now :P

Comment: Gotta love when I come back to this 6 years later for the exact same problem (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alpine registers a custom handler `do_hup_signal` to handle `SIGTERM` and `SIGHUP` ([pico/osdep/signals.c](https://repo.or.cz/alpine.git/blob/refs/tags/v2.26:/pico/osdep/signals.c#l55)). Its function seems to be sending `COMP_GOTHUP` to the composer to begin shutting down of the program.

For `SIGINT` sent by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it seems that the code has to opt-in to process it by calling `intr_handling_on` and `intr_handling_off` ([alpine/signal.c](https://repo.or.cz/alpine.git/blob/refs/tags/v2.26:/alpine/signal.c#l660)) around the time-consuming part. The code needs to check whether `intr_pending` is set, then do the clean-up works (including cancelling the progress spinner at the bottom by calling `cancel_busy_cue`).

Hence the "cancellability" of actions depend on whether the developer has implemented it.

---

These are from a quick look at the source code after having to wait a few times (so not sure if other trigger exists). I haven't attempted to locate the part for connecting to IMAP mailboxes.

BTW: A recent mirror of its repository on GitHub like https://github.com/petemoore/alpine might help when doing code searches.